# Regex: Lookahead and then lookbehind from the lookahead position

Tags: .net, regex

I have a .net regex (and I have to use regex) which  currently works by simply matching any non word characters between capture groups (which are capturing test to pass to a method).

In most cases it works fine but in the case where the text to be passed to a method is a negative number the non-word match consumes the minus sign and passes the positive number to the method. To complicate things further the non word characters between capture groups might contain text like " - ", which should be consumed. The text might also be a currency value like " $200" and in this case the "$" should also be consumed.

What I tried was to consume the non word characters until one was followed by a digit, then check if that digit was preceeded by something other than the minus sign and only consume if it was. My regex for this was:

```
\W+(?!\d(?<![^-]))
```

however this doesn't seem to work as I expect as this still seems to consume my minus sign, resulting in a positive number being passed to my method.

Is my regex wrong? Or can I not look ahead and then lookbehind from the lookahead position?

How can I get the desired result  which is that this text:

```
" -100"
```

matches only the whitespace at the beginning. And this text:

```
" $200"
```

matches the whitespace and the $ sign.

and this text:

```
" - 100"
```

matches the whitespace, minus sign and following whitespace, but not the number.

An example can be found [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5CW%2B(%3F!%5Cd(%3F%3C!%5B%5E-%5D))&i=%20-100%0D%0A%20%24200%0D%0A%20-%20100)

Comment: Looks like you might use `\W+(?!(?<![^-])\d)` or better -  `\W+(?!(?<=-)\d)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can use

```
\W+(?!(?<=-)\d)
```

See the [regexstorm demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5CW%2B(%3F!(%3F%3C%3D-)%5Cd)&i=%20------100%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%24%24%24%23%23%23%24200%0D%0A%20-%20%20-%20-%20-%20-%20%20-100%0D%0A---100)

**Pattern explanation**:

- `\W+` - 1+ non-word characters
- `(?!(?<=-)\d)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if the 1+ non-word characters are followed with a digit `\d` that has a `-` in front of it (`(?<=-)`)

[image]

Comment: yep this seems to work, thanks. Just got the order of my lookbehind wrong!

Comment: It is more than just an order. `\W+(?!\d(?<![^-]))` matches 1+ non-word characters that are not followed with a digit that should not be a non-hyphen. Due to the lookbehind, the lookahead will always return true because a digit is not a hyphen.